# Finding and recording all indexes of a given term from a file

Tags: python, file

So basically I'm trying to write a program that finds each index of a given term in a text file, and then adds all those indexes to a text file. Here's what I've tried:

```
with open('jobs.txt', 'r') as e:
    f = e.read() 
    list = []
    search = "n"
    index = 0
    while search in e:
        e.seek(index)
        i = e.read().find(search)
        index = index + int(i) # so the idea is that each time an index with that letter is found, 
                           #it gets recorded, and then, so that it doesn't repeat itself in the list, 
                           #I'm having the program start reading the file from that given index
        list.extend(''.join(str(i)))
        print(list)
```

however, what I'm getting is this:

[]

Anyone have any advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: absolutely nothing, my bad for adding it

Comment: could you show an example input and expected output as well?

Comment: the variable "search" is the input - the output was just a blank list

Comment: Read up on [`str.find(sub[, start[, end]])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=find#str.find)

Comment: I don't quite understand.

Could you elaborate - I read the page that was linked

what I tried was

            i = search.find(f, sub[start: index])
        index = index + int(i)
        list.extend(''.join(str(i)))

it just returns a blank list again